# Querying multiple nested objects on multiple paths

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html#nested-query) multiple nested objects **on different paths** in Elasticsearch? I can query one nested object on one path but I can't find the correct syntax to query two objects on different paths.

I need to query with the logic like the following:

```
{'query': {
   'bool': {
       'must': [
           'nested': {
               'path': 'Diagnosis',
               'query': {
                   'bool': {
                       'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis.Diagnosis': {'query': "epidemia"}}}]
                   }  
               }
           },
           'nested': {
               'path': 'Demographic',
               'query': {
                   'bool': {
                       'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Demographic.Gender': {'query': "female"}}}]
                   }  
               }
           }
       ]
   }
}}
```

The ultimate goal is to denormalize my PostgreSQL DB data (72 tables, over 1600 columns in total) and be able to use boolean queries over it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It works, I missed curly brackets around `nested` query.
The correct way:

```
{'query': {
   'bool': {
       'must': [
           {'nested': {
               'path': 'Diagnosis',
               'query': {
                   'bool': {
                       'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis.Diagnosis': {'query': "epidemia"}}}]
                   }  
               }
           }},
           {'nested': {
               'path': 'Demographic',
               'query': {
                   'bool': {
                       'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Demographic.Gender': {'query': "female"}}}]
                   }  
               }
           }}
       ]
   }
}}
```

Comment: Syntax is correct, but when using inner_hits{} with 2 different paths, Elastic doesn't return any results.

Using inner_hits with twice the same path, DOES return results.. :(